# Rails export to CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

I am trying to export my data to CSV file n allow it to be downloaded. Instead of the foregin key i want to fetch the name of that data from the related model. But i am still getting the foreign key.

```
//Controller
@missions = Mission.where({:status => 1}).order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { render text: @missions.to_csv }
    end

// Model
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |mission|
        csv << mission.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to refer the `region_id` foreign key to its `regions.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a has_many relationship setup correctly, you will be able to access the name of a mission's first region using:

```
mission.regions.first.name
```

or outside your loop, you could return the region name of the first Mission using:

```
Mission.first.regions.first.name
```

If each mission is only supposed to have one region, you may want to change has_many to has_one. In this case you can drop the plural regions and replace it with region like below:

```
Mission.first.region.name
```

After this is setup, the following tutorial should help you with the rest:

https://www.lockyy.com/posts/rails-4/exporting-csv-files-in-rails

Comment: i am getting the following undefined method `first' for #<Mission:0x007f8c622d94c0>

Comment: When i try "mission.region.name" i get the following error - undefined method `map' for "New York":String

Comment: .first is a method to elect the first object of Mission. You're receiving an undefined method because you're using it in within an .each block - which is iterating over each Mission object.

Do you have a has_one or has_many relationship between Mission and Region?